# Java's instanceof odd behavior

Tags: java, boolean, instanceof

Can anybody explain why the if statement below evaluates false?

```
public void addShapeToWhiteboard(PolyLine shape)
{
   Window.alert("2");
   if(shape instanceof PolyLine)
   {
      Window.alert("3");
      this.whiteboard.add((PolyLine)shape);
      Window.alert("3.5");
   }    
   this.whiteboard.draw();
   Window.alert("4");
}
```

it takes in a "PolyLine" object, but instanceof returns false because I get an alert of "2" followed by an alert of "4" and have no clue how it's even possible.

Comment: can we see the code that invokes this?

Comment: Please provide more information:
If you can provide the exact class of PolyLine it would help; is it javafx.scene.shape.Polyline or another class?
Show us how this code is called; what object is being passed in as shape?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe shape is null? instanceof returns false in such a case.

Comment: Thanks! I blanked out on that... I printed out the Class, and that made me dismiss the idea of it being null, but sure enough, it was.

Answer (score 11):

I bet `shape` is passed as `null`, and `null` is not an instance of any class.